# After installing apache, what is the right way to set up PHP?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I just got Apache to run.  Now I need to install php and make a development environment.  When I will need to place php files to be run on the server, is there a directory like "src" that I should create and place my php scripts there?  Or what is the good-practice way of doing this sort of thing?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What Operating system?

Comment: Ubuntu Operating System

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these sites

http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/step-by-step-ubuntu-904-jaunty-lamp-server-setup.html

They will step you through the whole process, including getting a database setup.

Comment: That tutorial was helpful.  But it left me with an error on the last step which is basically a "page not found" when I try to get to the php file via the browser.  Can it be an apache thing rather than a PHP problem?  Maybe a paths issue?  the .php file is in /var/www/ and I try to access it with localhost/filename.php

Comment: It could be any of several things... what error do you get in the Apache log files at the same time the request fails?

Answer (score 1):

Apache has a so called document root. On Ubuntu this is `/var/www/`.

When you visit the server in your browser, the default`/var/www/index.html` file is served to you.

If you want to serve some php scripts, this is the directory where you'd want to place them.
You could for example replace the default `index.html` file in the document root with your own `index.php`.